# Vuetify outlined select label is cut off when inside a data table header

Tags: vuetify.js

The floating label on an outlined `v-select` or `v-autocomplete` is getting cut off.

Is this mis-use on my end, or a bug with Vuetify?

```
<v-data-table :headers="[{ value: 'name', text: 'name' }]">
  <template #[`header.name`]>
    <v-select
      :value="['a']"
      outlined
      label="I should not be cut off"
      bottom
      :items="[{text: 'a', value: 'a'}]"
      deletable-chips
      small-chips
      chips
      clearable
      multiple
      hide-actions
      hide-details />
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

https://codepen.io/codepen123456789/pen/jOKwQKR

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some padding to v-select
eg:

```
<v-select class="pt-1" ...
```

Comment: i thought i tried that but must have put it in the wrong place :)

Comment: Well, some time happens :) good luck for the next :P